# How to create a related page or content type with in an existing custom content type?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I have created a custom content type that is a product page. It takes various pieces of information relevant to creating a software product page. For example the products Name, System Requirements, and features and builds a custom page for each piece of software that I may make.

The issue is that I have a product page, and several ways to obtain the software:

1. Potential Trial version download from my site directly.
2. Link to Purchase from the Mac App Store,
3. And a link to Purchase it from a FastSpring store.

I am Trying to find a nice way to conceal that all behind one button on my product page, so that I do not have to clutter my Product page with 3 links to various ways to obtain the product. I just want to have a button "Get Product" that can load a separate page or equivalent.

What are some ways to do this in a semi automated way so that it can happen when I create a new product page and then have Drupal also make another page or something that I can fill in with links that I know to acquire the product?

Because I really don't want to manually make two separate content types one for the product and one for the product downloads links and then have to manage a releationship between them for all products.  Trying to make it so that the ways to obtain the product are included in  the product page content type in an elegant way.

Comment: Could you illustrate a bit more about what exactly are you trying to achieve? You have a product and want to access it through a variety of different nodes? Is there any checkout/store logic associated with this problem?

Comment: I have a product page, and several ways to obtain the software. 1. Potential Trial version download from my site. 2. Purchase from the Mac App Store, 3. Purchase from my FastSpring store. Trying to find a nice way to conceal that all behind one button on my product page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concern is merely visual, you can use Fields to separate the different buying options then use Field Groups to separate them using, for instance, an accordion. You could then use javascript to control/open/close the items on the tabs.